# Pip3 install throwing error on raspberry pi 3 Raspbian-Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, python-3, pip

I am trying to install a python 3 library on a raspberry pi 3 running Raspbian-Jessie.

```
sudo pip3 install LIBRARY
```

However, regardless of what library I try to install, I am getting this error:

```
Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 417, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1426, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1149, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 837, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 421, in wrap_socket
    raise timeout('select timed out')
socket.timeout: select timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 313, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.piwheels.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it? I already tried installing multiple libraries (dlib, numpy, keras) and the result is the same. I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error log, it seems to be an issue with the SSL protocol being used:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1149, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError
```

This seems to be related to the recent blackout in supporting TLS 1.0 and 1.1 for `pip`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765614/1526703) answer for details.

In summary, upgrade `pip` as follows:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

Then install the library package:

```
sudo pip3 install LIBRARY
```

Comment: On Stretch I ran `pip install --upgrade setuptools` followed by `pip install --upgrade pip` which upgraded to pip 9.0.3

`pip3 install --upgrade pip` worked for pip3

Comment: @Milliways It depends on the version of the TLS being used. If its >=1.2, then it should all work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the (soon-to-be-obsolete) `Jessie`, but the Foundation now has [wheels](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/piwheels/) for most libraries - although I do not know if this was propagated to `Jessie`

I recently (October 2017) installed pre-configured libraries with `apt install python3-scipy python3-matplotlib` which should be your first step.