# Pip3 not installing jupyter

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, pip

I am having issues with my Raspberry pi not able to install jupyter notebook for python 3.4 when i do try to install jupyter i am getting the following error.

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
    Downloading/unpacking jupyter
      Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Downloading/unpacking ipykernel (from jupyter)
      Downloading ipykernel-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (108kB): 108kB downloaded
    Cleaning up...
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2595, in _dep_map
        return self.__dep_map
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2457, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
        requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
        req_to_install.extras):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2401, in requires
        dm = self._dep_map
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2597, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2621, in _compute_dependencies
        parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2721, in parse_requirements
        "version spec")
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2697, in scan_list
        raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
    ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'pytest ==3.2.*', 'at', '*')

    Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip3 install throwing error on raspberry pi 3 Raspbian-Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82746/pip3-install-throwing-error-on-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie)

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip3 install --upgrade pip` to update pip to `pip 9.0.3`